# Minimum value Jinja

Tags: null, jinja2, return-value, minimum

I have a Jinja template with a table that has 5 columns for each row. Column 1 to 4 are variable string representation of numbers (floating point decimal), column 5 shows the minimum value of these 4 columns using the following code;

```
{{ ['1', '2', '3', '4'] | min }}
```

This works fine, as long as all 4 of the columns are populated. Once one of the columns is empty nothing is returned.

```
{{ ['1', '2', '3', ''] | min }}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

---

*Note: the original question mentioned a list of integer `[1, 2, 3 ,4]` but after [pretty printing](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.pprint) them, I realised those were actually string representation of integers.*

Comment: I'd look for (or write) a filter, which removes undefined values from a list, and then do something like `[1, 2, 3 ,4]|cleanup_list|min`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your [`pprint`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.pprint) showed you that you do have string representation of integers — `'1'` — and not integers — `1` — in your variables, what you can, now, do is to [`reject`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.reject) the empty strings.

For extra care, I also thrown a [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) of the [`trim`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.trim) filter, so, if you have a blank string — e.g. with only spaces — then, this case will also be covered up.

So, given:

```
{{ ['1', '2', '', '4', ' '] | map('trim') | reject('eq','') | min }}
```

This gives the expected: `'1'`

---

If you do have integers, you can select only the numeric values out of a list with the [`select` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.select) and the [`number` test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-tests.number).

Given:

- ```
  {{ [1, 2, None, 4] | select('number') | min }}
  ```

Or

- ```
  {{ [1, 2, '', 4] | select('number') | min }}
  ```

Those both yield `1` as you would expect it.